# Export all interfaces/types from one file in TypeScript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

The direct interface to my library is captured by

```
index.d.ts
```

which is currently auto-generated from

```
index.ts
```

in my package.json file for my project, typings/types properties point to this index.d.ts file, which is to my understanding, how it should be. All good so far.

However, there are some more types that I would like to export from index.d.ts that are not currently expressed in index.d.ts.

For example I have some manually created types in

```
foo.d.ts
bar.d.ts
```

and I want these to be expressed in index.d.ts.

The only way I think that might work, is to import the foo.d.ts/bar.d.ts types into index.d.ts and then in turn export them from that file.

However, I am having trouble with that!

Here is what I tried:

```
// index.ts

import {IBar} from '../bar.d.ts'
import {IFoo} from '../foo.d.ts'

// ... do some stuff with index.ts yadda yadda

export type IBar = IBar; // doesn't seem to work
export interface IFoo = IFoo; // doesn't seem to work
```

is this possible? How do I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can export them directly if you don't need to use them.

```js
export * from '../foo/bar';
```

Or if you need to export only some of them you can use.

```js
export { IFoo, IBar} from '../foo/bar';
```

Or if you want to rename them during export you can do:

```js
export { IFoo as IOther, IBar as Dogs } from '../foo/bar';
```

You can read more about them in the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: This wasn't working for me, ultimately it turned out to be because of using default types. like if `IFoo` is defined like `export default class IFoo { ..... }`, then you index.ts needs to do `export {default as IFoo} from '../foo/bar';`

Comment: `export * from "..."` results in an error with the library where I'm trying to use it `module ... has no exported member`. However, if I explicitly export the object I'm trying to consume it works fine.  `export { myThing} from "..."`. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

I think the other answers will work. If you do need to use IFoo and IBar in the file, then this is what to do:

```
import * as IFooImport from '../foo.d.ts';

// use IFooImport

export import IFoo = IFooImport.IFoo;
```

This works, but a little awkward with the "export import" syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! To export everything, I did `export import myThings = myThings;`

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
export {IBar} from '../bar.d.ts'
export {IFoo} from '../foo.d.ts'
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work in easiest way i found you can follow the example of aws-cdk;

the things to check are:

1. use relative paths for the internal imports amoung the files of your modules (e.g. import {a} from './subdir1/file1') => this is so when transpiled the transpiled file references remain valid under the dist hierarchy
2. in your index.ts you need one 'export *' line per file; can generate with a find + sed

```
    // find . -type f -exec echo {} \;  | sed 
    //     's/\(.*\)\.ts/export \* from \"\1\"/'  
    export * from "./subdir1/file1"
    export * from "./subdir1/file2"
    export * from "./subdir2/file1"
```

this examples shows how to set up package.json ;  look at attrs main, module, types, files, build:esm, build:types
https://github.com/tomchen/example-typescript-package/blob/main/package.json

Then subsequently in your target code you can do things like

```
    import * as somenamespace from "@somepublisher/somemodule";
    import { SomeOtherClass } from "@somepublisher/somemodule";
    const x = new somenamespace.SomeClass();
    const y = new SomeOtherClass();
```