# What is the correct why to export a all members of module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

What is the correct why to export a all members of module in TypeScript ?

How we can export all members of Declarations.ts without writing export type A = ..., export type B= ..., sort of bundle them and export all together.

Here is the example:

```
Declarations.ts
type A = {};
type B = {};
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168733/typescript-export-all-functions-in-a-namespace

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583372/export-all-interfaces-types-from-one-file-in-typescript-project

Comment: Tnx but this posts are more related to importing module members not to exporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an item from one module should be used in another module, it should be exported:

```
export type A = {};
export type B = {};
```

There is no workaround. Imports and exports are supposed to be explicitly defined in TypeScript, this way they can be managed efficiently.

Comment: Tnx, I was looking for some shortcut and wanted someone to confirm there is no other way.